# sequential model give a different result at every run

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a python script for building a keras sequential model. Everytime i am getting different results without any changes in script. kindly have a look on script. where i am wrong please help.

```
thedata = pandas.read_csv("C:/User/Downloads/LSTM/data.csv", sep=', ', delimiter=',', header='infer', names=None)

np.random.seed(1337)

x = thedata['Review']
y = thedata['Polarity_Numeral']
x = x.iloc[:].values
y = y.iloc[:].values

tk = Tokenizer(num_words=40000, lower=True, split=" ")
tk.fit_on_texts(x)
x = tk.texts_to_sequences(x)    
max_len = 120
x = pad_sequences(x, maxlen=max_len)
max_features = 40000
testx = x[51000:52588]
print (testx)
testy = y[51000:52588]
x = x[0:50999]
y = y[0:50999]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=max_len))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128 , dropout_W=0.3, dropout_U=0.3, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, W_regularizer=l2(0.2)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.summary()
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.00)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam,metrics = ['accuracy'] )
model_history = model.fit(x, y=y, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=1,validation_split = 0.2)
model.save('C:/User/Downloads/model.h5')
model.save_weights('C:/User/Downloads/weight_model.h5')

predictions = model.predict(testx)
print (predictions)
```

On first time run, i am getting i.e 57%
On Second time run .. 53%
On third .. 55%
Everytime it is changing randomly.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using the tensorflow backend? Than it might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2280).

Comment: About `tk.fit_on_texts(x)`, is that some kind of training? If so, you should also save your x and y and make sure they are exactly the same for both the new and the loaded model.

Comment: yeah , for text preprocessing.  I am not able to understand exactly what is happening. same data set in training and in testing side, same model i am loading, still its giving different accuracy.

Comment: @user this is because weights are randomly initialised, try my code below.

Answer (score 5):

> This code is for tensorflow backend

This is because the weights are initialised using random numbers and hence you will get different results every time. This is expected behaviour. To have reproducible result you need to set the random seed as:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

# Setting the seed for numpy-generated random numbers
np.random.seed(37)

# Setting the seed for python random numbers
rn.seed(1254)

# Setting the graph-level random seed.
tf.set_random_seed(89)

from keras import backend as K

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
      inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

#Force Tensorflow to use a single thread
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)

K.set_session(sess)

# Rest of the code follows from here on ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running "exactly" that code, know that you're entirely creating a **new model**.

You're not loading a model, you're not adding your own weights to the model. 
You're simply creating a new model, with an entirely new random set of weights.

So, yes, it will produce different results. There is nothing wrong.

---

You probably should be using some kind of "load saved model" (perhaps `model.load_weights()`) if you want the same model to be kept. (In case you have the model saved somewhere)

Or you should "set_weights()" at some point after creating the model (if you know what weights you want, or if you have your weights saved)

Or you can use the initializers in each layer (as mentioned in another answer), if you want a new model with known weights.

Comment: run exactly the same code and saved trained model in a directory , testing accuracy was 69.269%  and  then wrote another script for loading trained model by using:    load_model('C:/User/Downloads/model.h5') and    model.load_weights('C:/User/Downloads/weight_model.h5')  and then model.predict(testx).        i got 66.6246% testing accuracy.

Comment: @MR.Robot, the question was deleted, it was indeed way to vague. I guess a basic tutorial on what neural networks do and how would answer that, though.

Comment: @DanielMöller here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926155/tf-idf-have-ability-to-extract-feature-at-4-different-level-how-i-can-get-the-c      ill be very thankful  sir

Answer (score 1):

with a quick look i don't see anything wrong..
you should remember that when you compile your model, keras randomly initializes all the weights in your model (you can also specify how you would like this to be done, or if you don't want it to be random, but the default is usually fine). So every time you compile you will get different weights and different results... given enough epochs they should all converge to the same result.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i don't want it to be random. How can i specify my values? how to fix the results. i was just checking thats why i gave epochs-1 , it wont take too much time to execute. once it will get fix, then give enough epochs.

Comment: you can specify the initialization you want for each layer, see the documentation:
https://keras.io/initializers/
you can se it to ones or zeros, or the identity matrix (that one is probably the best..) if you want.. make sure you set the bias to a constant and not random as well.
but i really don't know why you would want to do that... the initial randomness is fine and will converge in the best way. if you set all the weights to the same constant, it could interfere with the convergence.

Comment: thanks i will see  https://keras.io/initializers/ , i want constant result because i need to save trained model in a directory and then load that model in different script and test again. It should give the same result. This is just for saving the time.

Comment: you can achieve that by simply saving and loading the model, without re-compiling it in the second script. if you load the same model (same compliation! without another compilation!) it should do that.

Comment: i have tried to load trained model in different script.  commands:      
   model = Sequential()
  .....All layers....
model.summary()                                                                                 del model
model = load_model('C:/User/Downloads/model.h5')
model.load_weights('C:/User/Downloads/weight_model.h5')

predictions = model.predict(testx)
print (predictions)

Comment: And it does not work as expected? If you have a problem with savind and loading models, you should create a separate question for that.

Comment: Trained model accuracy was 51.82%  but when i tried to run different script(load trained model) , first time it gave 51.88%, 2nd time its 51.82% and 3rd time again i run that different script it gave 51.76%.  So this is difference. Is it fine? it should not be so i think. because same model i am loading.

Comment: yeah i am using  tensorflow backend for keras. I didn't get you. which issue? its related to tensorflow.

Comment: Keras does not reset weights when you **compile** the model. His code is simply creating an entire **new model**.

Comment: thanks Daniel for the correction.
either way - you shouldn't create a whole new model everytime, just
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
and you have your old model. it also includes the weights.. so you don't need to load them separately...
if you load the same model twice and run it on the same data it should give you the exact same result...